# Control how an elasticsearch java QueryBuilder is converted into a String

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

The following code emits an elasticsearch query that is too verbose for my liking -

```
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilder;
import static org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders.termQuery;

public class MyQueryPrinter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        QueryBuilder myQuery = termQuery("brand", "gucci");
        System.out.println(myQuery.toString());
        /* prints - 
          {
            "term" : {
                "brand" : {
                    "value" : "gucci",
                    "boost" : 1.0
                    }
                }
            }
         */
    } 
}
```

I'd like to print the shortest possible query json-

```
{
    "term" : {
        "brand" : "gucci"
    }
}
```

The code also automatically "pretty-prints" (i.e. indents) the json.

**How can I control how `QueryBuilder` is converted into a String?**

Thanks!!

p.s. - I'm using Elasticsearch 5.5.3 via                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                maven -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: No. I ended up implementing custom json serialization which removes "hard-coded" default fields.